# How to setup node-googlemaps? Lacking some implied knowledge about installing Node packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, npm

I am trying to use the node-googlemaps npm package at https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps. The documentation assumes the user knows the general NodeJS package installation process.

So first, I install it with npm:

```
npm install googlemaps
```

Now in my server.js root file, I know I need to import the actual file. Something similar to:

```
var gmaps = require('./node_modules/googlemaps/libs/index');
```

But I this is not correct. Perhaps I am missing some convention for installing NodeJS packages. In which case I would love to learn!

The README.md mentions setting up the config like so:

```
var publicConfig = {
  key: '<YOUR-KEY>',
  stagger_time:       1000, // for elevationPath
  encode_polylines:   false,
  secure:             true, // use https
  proxy:              'http://127.0.0.1:9999' // optional, set a proxy for HTTP requests
};
var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);
```

But I get an error "GoogleMapsAPI" is not defined. Makes sense, I haven't imported the js file. So how do I do that? What is the standard process for installing/including NodeJS packages to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

a) When you install a package to your project, you should use the `--save` option, so that it can be tracked in your project's `package.json` file. Among other things, it helps when you're committing things to version control, as you can exclude your node_modules directory from the repository.

```
npm install googlemaps --save
```

b) When you're calling `require` for a package from NPM, you don't need to type the full path! Just use:

```
var GoogleMapsAPI = require('googlemaps');

var publicConfig = {
  key: '<YOUR-KEY>',
  stagger_time:       1000, // for elevationPath
  encode_polylines:   false,
  secure:             true, // use https
  proxy:              'http://127.0.0.1:9999' // optional, set a proxy for HTTP requests
};

var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);
```

It'll automatically get you the exported object of whatever is defined as the package's 'main' file - which in this case, is `lib/index.js`, which exports the GoogleMapsAPI constructor.

Comment: I am not at my computer right now, but just wondering, will writing `var gmaps = require('googlemaps');` allow me to successfully call `var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);` in my routes? Does NPM also give access to `gmaps` universally throughout my server app?

Comment: Ah, no - `require` will rarely (if ever?) provide global variables to the environment, you'll usually end up requiring the module in every file you use it. Looking at the source code, the variable that `require("googlemaps")` exports *is* `GoogleMapsAPI`. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Updated! I agree that the docs were strangely unclear about what's being exported from the module...

Comment: Thanks so much! haha I bet this Stack Overflow question will help someone else down the line too :)